# how to call one .js variable information into another .js file in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

i am new in react-native, i am tried to pass variable one js file to another js file.
I want to call one variable from one of .js file to another .js file.
from firstPage.js file i want data to use another .js file. here i am creating **secondePage.js** ,call data from **firstPage.js**

how can i call them in react native ? how can i display data for the secondePage.js.

anyone can help me to do that here,
thanks for your helping in advance!

firstPage.js

```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
        
        const TestOne =() =>{
          const [data, setData] = useState();
          useEffect(() => {
            fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5")
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((data) => setData(data))
              .catch((error) => console.error(error));
          }, []);
        
          if (!data) {
            return <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>;
          }
          console.log(data);
        }
    export default TestOne;
```

secondPage.js

```
    import pageOne, {data} from "./pageOne";
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
    import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Dimensions, RefreshControl, Text, SafeAreaView, Fragment } from 'react-native';
    
    
    const TrailTwo = () => {
        //console.log(TestTwo());
        console.log(data)
    }
    export default TrailTwo;
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2 screens which are totally independent of each other.
You can access the `data` via `redux`,
For that `data` needs to be stored in `redux` in `TestOne` so that `TrailTwo` can access that .

You can check this https://react-redux.js.org/

Feel free for doubts